# nginx: routing multiple URLs to one html file

Tags: nginx, routing, redirect

we render part of our site to static files, similar to what jekyll does. For instance, we have files:

```
index.html
about-us.html
```

the problem is, sometimes the names change and we end up with:

```
index.html
company.html (former about-us.html)
```

Now, is there an easy way to redirect all the requests to http://example.com/about-us.html to http://example.com/company.html without the need to restart the server?

Something like apache's .htaccess would be great because the whole root document directory is generated and synchronized across multiple servers so we could simply re-generate this .htaccess equivalent and put all necessary redirections there.

thanks!
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way in nginx to put redirects in a htaccess-like file (mainly because it's a performance killer). You will have to do this in the nginx configuration (and reload nginx in order to make the redirects available).

To get this deployed to different servers, you could use a directory structure like this:

Docroot:

```
/var/www/$hostname/html
```

Local Nginx conf (gets included via main nginx.conf:

```
/var/www/$hostname/conf/nginx.conf
```

synchronize both directories to your other servers and make sure they get reloaded.